# Microsoft SQL Server: run arbitrary query and save result into temp table

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Given an *arbitrary* `select` query, how can I save its results into a temporary table?

To simplify things let's assume the `select` query does not contain an `order by` clause at the top level; it's not dynamic SQL; it really is a `select` (not a stored procedure call), and it's a single query (not something that returns multiple result sets).  All of the columns have an explicit name.  How can I run it and save the results to a temp table?  Either by processing the SQL on the client side, or by something clever in T-SQL.

I am not asking about any particular query -- obviously, given some particular SQL I could rewrite it by hand to save into a temp table -- but about a rule that will work in general and can be programmed.

**One possible "answer" that does not work in general**

For simple queries you can do
`select * into #tmp from (undl) x` where `undl` is the underlying SQL query.  But this fails if `undl` is a more complex query; for example if it uses common table expressions using `with`.

For similar reasons `with x as (undl) select * into #tmp from x` does not work in general; `with` clauses cannot be nested.

**My current approach, but not easy to program**

The best I've found is to find the top level `select` of the query and munge it to add `into #tmp` just before the `from` keyword.  But finding which `select` to munge is not easy; it requires parsing the whole query in the general case.

**Possible solution with user-defined function**

One approach may be to create a user-defined function wrapping the query, then `select * into #tmp from dbo.my_function()` and drop the function afterwards.  Is there something better?

- More detail on why the simple approach fails when the underlying uses CTEs.  Suppose I try the rule `select * into #tmp from (undl) x` where `undl` is the underlying SQL.  Now let `undl` be `with mycte as (select 5 as mycol) select mycol from mycte`.  Once the rule is applied, the final query is `select * into #tmp from (with mycte as (select 5 as mycol) select mycol from mycte) x` which is not valid SQL, at least not on my version (MSSQL 2016).  `with` clauses cannot be nested.
- To be clear, CTEs must be defined at the top level before the `select`.  They cannot be nested and cannot appear in subqueries.  I fully understand that and it's why I am asking this question.  An attempt to wrap the SQL that ends up trying to nest the CTEs will not work.  I am looking for an approach that will work.
- "Put an `into` right before the `select`".  This will certainly work but requires parsing the SQL in the general case.  It's not always obvious (to a computer program) which `select` needs to change.  I did try the rule of adding it to the last `select` in the query, but this also fails.  For example if the underlying query is

`with mycte as (select 5 as mycol) select mycol from mycte except select 6`

then the `into #x` needs to be added to the *second* select, not to the one that appears after `except`.  Getting this right in the general case involves parsing the SQL into a syntax tree.

Comment: *"for example if it uses common table expressions using with."* No it doesn't, it fails because your syntax is invalid. You most certainly can use a `SELECT ... INTO` with a CTE defined in the statement. If you are getting an error when trying to do so, include that attempt in your question.

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. `SELECT INTO` works, with or without CTEs. If `INTO` specifies a temporary table, you'll get a temporary table that will be deleted automatically when the connection closes.

Comment: `SELECT INTO` is an actual SELECT with an extra `INTO` clause. In all SELECT queries CTEs must be defined *before* the SELECT keyword. You can't define CTEs in subqueries. This has nothing to do with `INTO`

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have added some explicit detail on why a naive `select into` approach does not work.  @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, the CTEs must come before the select.  That is why simply wrapping the SQL does not work.  I am looking for a rule that does work.

Comment: It works. Your query is wrong. You can't have CTEs in subqueries, they must be defined before the query itself. That's the whole point of CTEs. They're named snippets that can be used in the query

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of a rule that will work in all cases please?

Comment: Put the CTEs before `SELECT`. You still haven't posted your query, only pseudo-code. You can write `WITH someCTE (....) SELECT ... INTO #tmp FROM someCTE INNER JOIN (Somesubquery..)`. The syntax doesn't change because of `INTO`

Comment: Instead of trying to put your query inside a `SELECT INTO` just put an `INTO right after the SELECT in your query

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I can write by hand some SQL to save into a temp table -- that's not the question.  I am looking for a general approach that will work with arbitrary `select` queries.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question some more with notes on the `into` clause.  I did try that approach too.

Comment: *"For similar reasons `with x as (undl) select * into #tmp from x` does not work in general; `with` clauses cannot be nested."* This statement is still n the question, and it is *still* wrong.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the correction but can you post an example SQL query that uses nested `with` clauses?  I have never got them to work.

Comment: It's not `select * into #tmp from (with mycte as (select 5 as mycol) select mycol from mycte) x` it's `with mycte as (select 5 as mycol) select mycol into #tmp from mycte`

Comment: What do you mean by a "nested `WITH` clause"? You don't nest `WITH`.

Comment: @Larnu that's exaclty right.  But how do I transform the underlying SQL text into the new query using `into #tmp`?  It's not as trivial as it sounds.  I give an example above where there is an `except` clause.  Short of actually parsing the SQL, I don't know of a rule to add it.

Comment: @Larnu that's exactly what I mean.  `with` clauses cannot be nested.  That's what I wrote in the question.

Comment: Why are you trying to nest `WITH`? If you want to define multiple CTEs, comma delimit them: `WITH CTE 1 AS (...), CTE2 AS( ...), CTE3 AS(...) SELECT ... FROM CTE1....`

Comment: As for using an `EXCEPT` with an `INTO`: `SELECT name, database_id
INTO #temp
FROM sys.databases
EXCEPT
SELECT 'master', 1;` is one method. Using a derived table would be another.

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to nest `with`.  I explicitly listed one of the approaches that *doesn't* work just to head off some possible wrong answers.  Sorry if that caused confusion.

Comment: *"I am not trying to nest `with`"* ... *"post an example SQL query that uses nested `with` clauses"* So you want an example, but don't want to do that? Why ask for an example then..?

Comment: @Larnu sorry I misunderstood your earlier comment where you said: "This statement is still n the question, and it is still wrong".  I thought you meant that the statement "with clauses cannot be nested" was wrong.  That's not what you meant.

Comment: Moderators, I believe I have incorporated the necessary clarifications into the question, so comments can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end creating a user-defined function appears to be the only general answer.  If `undl` is the underlying `select` query, then you can say

```
create function dbo.myfunc() returns table as return (undl)
go
select * into #tmp from dbo.myfunc()
go
drop function dbo.myfunc
go
```

The pseudo-SQL `go` indicates starting a new batch.  The `create function` must be executed in one batch before the `select`, otherwise you get a syntax error.  (Just separating them with `;` is not enough.)

This approach works even when `undl` contains subqueries or common table expressions using `with`.  However, it does not work when the query uses temporary tables.

Comment: You cannot easily use this in environment, where users are not permitted to create functions (esp in dbo schema).